# Select difference based on record having minimum and maximum date in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Below is my table let's call account

```
**ID        accountID       score        tracking_date
  1             1              3      2014-09-25 00:01:05
  2             2              4      2014-09-26 01:05:18
  3             1              6      2014-09-27 09:23:05
  4             2              9      2014-09-28 20:01:05
  5             1              1      2014-09-28 23:21:34
  6             3              7      2014-09-21 00:01:00
  7             2              1      2014-09-22 01:45:24
  8             2              9      2014-09-27 14:01:43
  9             3              1      2014-09-24 22:01:27
```

I want to select record with max date and also the difference of score with the records having tracking_date as minimum for that accountId. So I want output like below

```
  ID accountID score_with_maxdate diff_score_with_mindate  max_tracking_date
  1     1              1                     -2           2014-09-28 23:21:34
  2     2              9                      8           2014-09-28 20:01:05
  3     3              1                     -6           2014-09-24 22:01:27
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option.  We can self-join a subquery which finds both the min and max tracking dates, for each account, twice to your original table.  This will bring in all metadata for those max tracking date records, including the scores.

```
SELECT
    t1.accountID,
    t2.score AS score_with_maxdate,
    t2.score - t3.score AS diff_score_with_mindate,
    t1.max_tracking_date
FROM
(
    SELECT
        accountID,
        MAX(tracking_date) AS max_tracking_date,
        MIN(tracking_date) AS min_tracking_date
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY accountID
) t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.accountId = t2.accountID AND t2.tracking_date = t1.max_tracking_date
INNER JOIN yourTable t3
    ON t1.accountId = t3.accountID AND t3.tracking_date = t1.min_tracking_date
ORDER BY
    t1.accountID;
```

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

This is a somewhat tricky question.  I think conditional aggregation is a convenient way to solve the problem:

```
select min(t.id) as id, t.accountId,
       max(case when t.tracking_date = t2.max_td then t.score end) as score_with_maxdate,
       max(case when t.tracking_date = t2.max_td then t.score
                when t.tracking_date = t2.min_td then - t.score
                end) as diff_score_with_mindate,
       max(t.tracking_date) as max_tracking_date
from t join
     (select t2.accountId, min(t2.tracking_date) as min_td, max(t2.tracking_date) as max_td
      from t t2
      group by t2.accountId
     ) t2
     on t.accountId = t2.accountId
group by t.accountId;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon! I have not tried this because Tim answer is working. Will check it.

Answer (score 0):

Another hackish way of getting same results by using aggregate and string fucntion

```
select t.accountID,
  t.score_with_maxdate,
  t.score_with_maxdate - t.score_with_mindate score_with_maxdate,
  t.max_tracking_date
from(
  select accountID,
    substring_index(group_concat(score order by tracking_date desc),',', 1) + 0 score_with_maxdate,
    substring_index(group_concat(score order by tracking_date asc),',', 1) + 0 score_with_mindate,
    max(tracking_date) max_tracking_date
  from demo
  group by accountID
) t
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3cfecb/6)

But i would suggest you to go with other solutions mentioned by Tim & Gordon